# SQL Grouping by predefined date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fca3d/1

I'm trying to now add one row for each week in the year, and filter the contacts accordingly.  The new table will look like:

```
        Status 1    Status 2    Status 3
Week 1      3          4           2
Week 2      1          5           3
Week 3      2          2           4
```

I think that DATEADD needs to be used, however I'm at a loss in terms of how to begin changing my query.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a GROUP BY clause :

```
SELECT 
    WEEK(created),
    SUM(case WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Status3,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Status4,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Status5
FROM contacts
GROUP BY WEEK(created), YEAR(created);
```

It's important to also group by year, otherwise it would group by week regardless of the year.
Also, no row is created if there's no data during a week. You'd need another set of data for this.

**Edit**: Here is an example for SQL Server 2012 [[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/907/0)]

Comment: Wow, that's dead simple.  Any idea how I can display the Week in the first column?

Comment: @RobVious: Actually, the query I posted already do that. It returns the number of the week. If absolutely necessary, you could do something like `SELECT CONCAT("Week ", WEEK(created)), --...`.

Comment: @RobVious: One more thing: this is the MySQL syntax. There's probably an extract function for SQL Server, but the idea behind the query should be the same. (SQLFiddle was set to use MySQL and I didn't bother to confirm it was the right DBMS.)

Comment: Ah, you're right about the syntax issue.  I didn;t even notice that was MySQL; I'm looking for a SQL solution.